# Why does bytes.fromhex() treat some hex values strangely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to use the socket library in Python to send bytes of two hex digits to a piece of hardware programmed to accept them.  To create the bytes from a user-entered string of hex digits, I'm trying to use `bytes.fromhex()` method described [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex).

Why does the following:

```
hexstring = "bb 0D 02 55 55 5A ce"
data = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)
print(data)
```

give me:

```
b'\xbb\r\x02UUZ\xce'
```

instead of:

```
b'\xbb\x0d\x02\x55\x55\x5a\xce'
```

?

And how do I get it to produce the second output? I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: `'\x55'` is the printable ASCII character `'U'`, `'\x5A'` is the printable ASCII character `'Z'`, and `'\x0D'` is the ASCII character conventionally denoted by the escape string `'\r'`.  If you want a string displaying the `'\x..'` only format, where the hex code is explicitly visible for each character, well... you kind of have that already, in `hexstring`.   Don't worry about how the output string is *displayed* by the Python console—it's presumably more important to process its content and worry about how it's displayed on whatever system it ends up on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `bytes.fromhex()`. You'd get the same result if you entered your expected result into Python:

```
>>> b'\xbb\x0d\x02\x55\x55\x5a\xce'
b'\xbb\r\x02UUZ\xce'
```

The `repr()` representation of a `bytes` object will always use ASCII printable characters and short one-letter escape sequences where possible.

So `\x0d` is displayed as `\r`, because that's the ASCII code point for a carriage return. `\x55` is the printable ASCII character `U`, etc.

If this is an issue for you, you'll have to explicitly convert your `bytes` value to hexadecimal again:

```
>>> b'\xbb\r\x02UUZ\xce'.hex()
'bb0d0255555ace'
```

Comment: Thank you.  I realized that despite the way it is being displayed using ASCII printable characters and one-letter escape sequences, it is still being transmitted the way that I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Python automatically displays bytes that can be interpreted as printable ASCII as the characters they print. For example, `chr(0x55) == 'U'`, so Python just prints U instead of the hexcode. It is still the same data.